# How to calculate effect size using metafor when I don't have 2*2 table?

Tags: r, statistics, metafor

I wish to calculate my effect size based on the response ratio but my studies only have means of the treatment(no-tillage) and control(conventional tillage). However, my studies didn't provide variance or standard deviations. How do I go about this especially with  metafor. I get this error below

> dat <- escalc(measure="RR", m1i=NT,m2i=CT, data=dt)
> Error in escalc(measure = "RR", m1i = NT, m2i = CT, data = dt) :
> Cannot compute outcomes. Check that all of the required
> information is specified via the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Welcome to  stackoverflow, please provide sample code along with data what  you have tried.

Comment: Hi @Acha, please have a look at the following link which provides the detail about how to produce reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

`measure="RR"` is for (log) risk ratios. If you want response ratios (i.e., log transformed ratios of means), you need `measure="ROM"`. But you also need the sample sizes and standard deviations of the two groups. Otherwise, the sampling variances cannot be computed. See `help(escalc)` and see `help(dat.curtis1998)` for an example.

Comment: Thank you Prof Wolfgang. Though the studies selected didn't report sample sizes and standard deviations(SDs), I can compute my sample sizes from the study using experimental plots and replicates however for SDs, is it logical to calculate the SD for each group based on the extracted means from the studies? or must the SD be based on those extracted from each particular study?

Comment: You really need the SD of the measurements within studies. The SD of the means is something completely different.